# How to remove jQuery conflict in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, jquery, conflict

I am getting a **conflict** of **jQuery** and due to this some feature of Magento 2 not working . How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: have you added jquery? Magento2 already provided jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Magento2 already provided jquery lib check here`(\lib\web\jquery)`

You can use jquery function below way.

```
require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
      $(document).ready(function($) {
           alert("Abdul"); 
      });
 });
```